# How can i resolve the problem "can't resolve all parameters for EventlistComponent"

Tags: angular

I am trying to follow up with a video on pluralsight(Angular fundmental). I am following up with the Author to the letter, until he got to the section for dependency injection. As soon as in injected a service into the constructor, my app broke, I have searched the internet for possible solution, even stackoverflow here. This problem seems very common but are different thing that can cause this error message on the console "CAN'T RESOLVE ALL PARAMTERS FOR EVENTLISTCOMPONENT. I'm frustrated right now as I am thinking of abandoning learning Angular because of this.

This is my code.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'events-app',
  template: `
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    <events-list></events-list>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class EventsAppComponent {
  title = 'angular-fundamental';
}
```

**Event list component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from './shared/event.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'events-list',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Upcoming Events</h1>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5" *ngFor="let event of events">
          <event-thumbnail [event]="event"></event-thumbnail>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class EventListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any[]
  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    his.events = this.eventService.getEvents()
  }
}
```

**Event service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class EventService {
  getEvents() {
    return EVENTS //EVENTS is an array of events not included here
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { EventsAppComponent } from './events-app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './nav/nav-bar.component'
import { EventListComponent } from './events/event-list.component';
import { EventThumbnailComponent } from './events/events-thumbnail.component'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EventsAppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    EventListComponent,
    EventThumbnailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [EventsAppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: `his.events` should be `this.events`

Comment: I got it capture correctly on my code, but why that console error "Can't resolve all parameters"

Comment: It is most probably due to a missing provider. Dependency Injection injects a class into another, but you need to provide it in order for it to be instanciated.
It should probably be imported and provided in your app.module.ts file, in the providers array.

Comment: i did that in the injectable decorator, by setting the providedIn property to root

Comment: Unfortunately the info you have provided seems to be running https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8mc8gg